# Is a the sign of the Lyapunov exponent a sufficient condition for chaos?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am wondering if the sign of the Lyapunov exponent is a sufficient condition for chaotic orbits.

Consider the unimodal map
$$x_{k+1}=ax_k-x_k^2 \qquad 0<a<4, \quad x_k\geq 0.$$ 
We define the Lyapunov exponent as, $$\lambda(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\log|f'(x_i)|$$ for each iteration $n$. For the above map for $x_0=3$ and $a=4$, we can show that $\lambda(3)=\log(2)>0$. 
Is this a sufficient condition that no chaotic orbits occur for these parameter values of this map?

Comment: Your example is confusing. A positive Lyapunov exponent is at least a strong indication *for* chaos, not against it. Also, the definitions and conditions of chaos have been dissected in multiple questions already. You will probably get better answers if you more precisely elaborate why you are skeptical about this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Simply stated: Does a negative Lyapunov exponent guarantee chaos?

Comment: You got the sign wrong. **Positive** Lyapunov exponents indicate chaos, not negative ones.